# Build a path in C using getenv

Tags: c, windows

I am trying to build a path in C which will point to:

```
%appdata%/some/file.xx
```

I am trying to do it using [these functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tehxacec%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) as it follows:

```
char *getenv( 
   const char *varname 
);
wchar_t *_wgetenv( 
   const wchar_t *varname 
);
char *appData = getenv("AppData"); //so far so good

char *myURL;
myURL = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));

//when I comment the next two lines, everything is ok, but if I uncomment them I get tons of errors
strcpy(myURL, appData);
strcat(myURL, "/some/path.xx");

FILE *myFile = fopen(myURL, "r");
```

Any hints on how can I have this working ? I have been struggling with this for some days and I couldn't fix it yet.

I am also aware of another possibilities like: [SHGetSpecialFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762204%28VS.85%29.aspx), [SHGetFolderPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [SHGetKnownFolderIDList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762187%28VS.85%29.aspx) but I wasn't able to use them as I am not so advanced.

Comment: You should also post those tons of errors for the benefit of readers.

Comment: If considering `SHGetFolderPath`  you should tag your question as being Windows specific.

Comment: Ok. I will also add another tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof(char)` is always 1.

So

```
myURL = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

allocates only one byte. That is not enough. You should always test `malloc`  against failure, and [you should not cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/841108) when coding in *C* (and in C++, better use `std::string` or at least `operator new`).

Of course you need to `#include`  all of `<stdlib.h>` (for `malloc` & `getenv` & `exit` ...) and `<stdio.h>` (for `fopen` & `perror` ...) & `<string.h>` (for `strlen`, `strcat`, `strcpy` ....)

And you are not sure that `getenv("AppData")` succeeds by returning a non `NULL` string.

So you should try:

```
 char *appdata = getenv("AppData");
 if (!appdata) 
    appdata="/some/default/path";
 size_t appdatalen = strlen(appdata);
 char* restpath= "/some/path.xx";
 size_t restpathlen = strlen(restpath);
 size_t fullpathlen = // 1 additional byte for terminating \0
     appdatalen+restpathlen+1;
 char *fullpath =  malloc(fullpathlen);
 if (!fullpath) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
 strcpy (fullpath, appdata);
 strcat (fullpath, restpath);
 FILE *myFile = fopen(fullpath, "r");
```

I'm using `fullpath`, not `myURL`, since `fopen` cannot deal with [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator)s (like `http://some.host.org/some/path`). If you need to deal with genuine URLs you need some [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) client library like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

You might instead of a heap allocated `fullpath` use a local buffer of `PATH_MAX` characters. See also [this thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/289427/40065).

Don't forget to compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), and learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`). Additional compiler options like `-fsanitize=address` might be helpful. Addition debugging tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) also are helpful. Some of these tools might not be available on some operating systems (for beginners in C, I recommend using Linux).

Read about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) & [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

Comment: Then, how should I correctly use the `malloc()` in this case ? Should I use `myURL = (char *)malloc(256*sizeof(char));` ? I've tried this way and I get exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Alexander You should use `myURL = malloc(256);` to allocate a string with maximum length of 255 since `sizeof(char)` is 1 and you should not cast the return value from `malloc`. But Basile's answer is better since it actually calculates how many bytes you need to allocate.

Comment: I got it. I will try your way @Basile. `URL` was just a typo. There should've been `path` instead.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch do you have any idea why VS2012 is underlining the `malloc` word from `char *fullpath =  malloc(fullpathlen);` and it says that: `a value of type void* cannot be used to initialize an entity of type char*` ?

Comment: @alexander, he most likely just forgot the `char*` in front of the malloc. Do add it like you used it in your code originally